# Passing multiple value for a parameter in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have written the query below:

```
SET @City = 'London,Lyon,Kln';
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@City, ',',@r:=@r+1),',',-1) City
FROM (SELECT @r:=0) x,
(SELECT 'x' xx 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'v' xx
    UNION
    SELECT 'z' xx) z;
```

Which returns Cities in table format & now i want to pass it as a parameter to a query like :

```
SET @City = 'London,Lyon,Kln';
SELECT * 
FROM Invoices 
WHERE City IN (
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( @City, ',',@r:=@r+1),',',-1
    ) City
    FROM (SELECT @r:=0) x,
    (SELECT 'x' xx 
        UNION
        SELECT 'v' xx 
        UNION
        SELECT 'z' xx) z
)
```

But when I execute this query it returns the records for 'Kln' city only, ie. for last city mentioned in `@City` variable. So please tell me how to get the records for all cities of `@City` variable.

Comment: I answered below, hoping I understand the setup. Am I correct in understanding that you have a table called invoices with a field called city and you want to be able to pass a dynamic query selecting all the results where city is in a particular list of cities?

Comment: This concept is limited to exactly 3 cities due to the `UNIONs`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent, I might write the query something like this:

```
SET @City = '"London","Lyon","Kln"';
SET @sql = concat('SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE City IN (',@City,')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```